# Adding multiple BigQuery JSON credential files in Node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, credentials

I've been working on a Node project that involves fetching some data from BigQuery. Everything has been fine so far; I have my credential.json file (from BigQuery) and the project works as expected.

However, I want to implement a new feature in the project and this would involve fetching another set of data from BigQuery. I have an entirely different credential.json file for this new dataset. My project seems to recognize only the initial credential.json file I had (I named them differently though).

Here's a snippet of how I linked my first credential.json file:

```
function createCredentials(){

    try{
        const encodedCredentials = process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY;

        if (typeof encodedCredentials === 'string' && encodedCredentials.length > 0) {
            const google_auth = atob(encodedCredentials);

        if (!fs.existsSync('credentials.json')) {
            fs.writeFile("credentials.json", google_auth, function (err, google_auth) {
                  if (err) console.log(err);
                  console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
                });
          }
      }

    } 

catch (error){
    logger.warn(`Ensure that the environment variable for GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY is set correctly: full errors is given here: ${error.message}`)
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
  }


}
```

Is there a way to fuse my two credential.json files together? If not, how can I separately declare which credential.json file to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If not, how can I separately declare which credential.json file to use?

What I would do I would create a function which is the exit point to BigQuery and pass an identifier to your function which credential to generate, This credential will then be used when calling BigQuery.

The below code assume you changed this

```
function createCredentials(){

    try{
        const encodedCredentials = process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY;
```

To this:

```
function createCredentials(auth){

    try{
        const encodedCredentials = auth;
```

And you can use it like this

```
    import BigQuery from '@google-cloud/bigquery';
    import {GoogApi} from "../apiManager" //Private code to get Token from client DB

    if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
        var a = require("babel-polyfill")
    }

    describe('Check routing', async () => {

        it('Test stack  ', async (done, auth) => {

            //Fetch client Auth from local Database

            //Replace the 2 value below with real values
            const tableName = "myTest";
            const dataset = "myDataset";

            try {

                const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                    projectId: `myProject`,
                    keyFilename: this.createCredentials(auth)
                });
                await bigquery.createDataset(dataset)
                    .then(
                        args => {
                            console.log(`Create dataset, result is: ${args}`)
                        })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(`Error in the process: ${err.message}`)
                    })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("err", err)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I don't still understand where I'm supposed to pass in the appropriate credentials.json file.

Comment: I marked in bold in my code, You use it when you create the `BigQuery` object `keyFilename: this.createCredentials(auth)`